# How to make Plotly Dash Date Picker Range and Button Work

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I'm using `Dash` by `Plotly` to create a dashboard but that would take Date Range as input. But I'm getting `TypeError` while trying to imitate the simple example shown in [here](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components). I don't understand what am I doing wrong. Below is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from datetime import datetime as dt

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    html.H1(children='AE Analytics Dashboard', style={'color': 'gray', 'text-align': 'center'}),
    html.Div(
        html.Div(
            dcc.Input(id='input-box', placeholder='Enter AE Name', type='text',value=''),
            dcc.DatePickerRange(
                id='date-picker-range',
                start_date_placeholder_text= 'Select a date!',
                end_date_placeholder_text='Select a date!'
            )
        ),
        html.Button('Submit', id='button'),
        # html.Div(id='output-container-button', children='Enter a value and press submit')
    )
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatePickerRange'

I'm Having following error while trying to use `html.Button`:

> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Button.**format**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. It was a silly mistake. Below is the corrected code for anyone's reference.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from datetime import datetime as dt

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    html.H1(children='AE Analytics Dashboard', style={'color': 'gray', 'text-align': 'center'}),
    html.Div(
        html.Div([
            dcc.Input(id='input-1-state', type='text', placeholder='AE Name', style={'text-align': 'center'}, value=''),
            dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id='date-picker-range',
            start_date_placeholder_text= 'Select a date!',
            end_date_placeholder_text='Select a date!'
        ),
            html.Button(id='submit-button', n_clicks=0, children='Submit')
            ]),
        ),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you explain ? I'm having similar error and I can't understand just looking at your code.

Comment: Whatever components you want to use inside a particular `Div`, you'll have to wrap them in an iterable like a list. Compare `html.Div` below `html.H1` between the question and the answer and let me know if you can spot the difference.